# Main thread warning for ajax functions

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a set of functions for ajax to deal with sending and receive data on POST and GET. But i get this warning on Chrome:

`Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated`

I am not clear on how to fix this warning, as i don't want to ignore it to end up with problems down the road.

This is my ajax function code:

```
var ajax = new function(){

    var self = this;

    self.x = function() {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            return new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{// code for IE6, IE5
            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    };

    self.send = function(url, callback, method, data, sync) {
        var x = self.x();
        x.open(method, url, sync);
        x.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (x.readyState == 4) {
                callback(x.responseText)
            }
        };
        if (method == 'POST') {
            x.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        }
        x.send(data)
    };

    self.get = function(url, data, callback, sync) {
        var query = [];
        for (var key in data) {
            query.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key]));
        }
        self.send(url + (query.length ? '?' + query.join('&') : ''), callback, 'GET', null, sync)
    };


    self.post = function(url, data, callback, sync) {
        var query = [];
        for (var key in data) {
            query.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key]));
        }
        self.send(url, callback, 'POST', query.join('&'), sync)
    };
};
```

What specifically is the cause of this warning and how would i go about correcting it to be in line with accepted standards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call your `send` method, make sure the last parameter (`sync`) is set to false. If set to true, it will execute the AJAX call asynchronously, and thus won't warn you about it.

Synchronous calls are indeed deprecated as it completely blocks the main thread while waiting for the response. This will in most cases completely block the browser's UI until the call has ended.

Comment: The issue is though, i am using AJAX to load HTML pages. So i do need it to technically `block` whilst it loads the page, given that the website should really do nothing until it has loaded the page. But if its deprecated what is the new standard way to handle that sort of thing ?

Comment: Simply display a white page, or even better, a little spinner to let the user know the HTML is loading. This way the browser is not blocked and the result doesn't change for the user. When you receive the HTML in the result of your AJAX call, you display it and remove the spinner, if you have one.